# Comodo Essentials SSL: Vestacp "SSL intermediate chain is not valid"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, vestacp

I'm trying to install Comodo Essential SSL via Vestacp here's that I did. I opened `www_example_com.crt` and copied the digest and pasted it into `SSL Certificate` box then opened `www_example_com.key` used to generate the ssl at the beginning which starts with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and pasted the digest into `SSL Key` box then copied the digest of the other 3 files in this order into one file and copied the whole digest and pasted it into `SSL Certificate Authority / Intermediate` box but I get `SSL intermediate chain is not valid`

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

Final digest looks like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I checked the certificate and the key and have no issue using https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

I restored a back up so the key file doesn't exist on the server now does it matter? It's the first time I try to install SSL so please assist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Authority digest must be the content of these files in this order

```
SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt 

USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
```